# Gtkmm: How to pause the execution of the application and wait for user input?

Tags: c++, user-interface, gtkmm

I am looking for a way to pause the execution of the application, without it becoming frozen, and when the user presses a button it promptly continues whatever it was doing at the moment it paused.

I wasn't able to find any documentation on this or on how to pause the execution for a certain amount of time. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: I tried using this: https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs/GLib-2.0/GLib.usleep.html as well as using the sleep()  commnad but instead of just pausing the application it makes it unresponsive. What I am trying to do is to visualize some parts of an algorithm using the GUI, but the output is displayed too fast and it is very difficult to understand it.

Comment: Pause what exactly? UI application is running so called "message pump loop". Do you want to stop that loop or what?

Comment: I am trying to pause an algorithm while it is solving a problem. It sends some parameters the the GUI, the GUI displays them and here the execution should pause. When the user presses a button the execution continues from that point.

Comment: Your algorithm should run in worker thread. You can pause that thread but not main GUI thread. Even in paused state UI shall have a chance to render on window surface. Rendering is made in GUI thread so it shall not be blocked.

Comment: I found the topic of std::condition_variables and I think that this would allow me to do what you described. Thanks very much for the information :)

Answer (score 1):

As you are saying "user interface", I recommend to go with modal dialogs.
Every UI library will have option to create modal dialogs.

Ask user to input in a modal dialog. The execution waits, till the modal dialog is closed. Use "Close" or "Ok" button to close the Modal dialog.